# US - Home Office Deduction As Both an Employee and For Self Employment

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, tax-deduction

I am a full time employee at a company which does not provide a regular office.  I work from home as a result.  I also have a non-related business where I work between 20 to 30 hours a week from my home office.

Can I deduct my home office expenses for both the business LLC tax filing and my personal tax filing?

Comment: You may not be able to deduct it either way. See past answers about hi.e offices, or https://www.irs.gov/uac/top-six-tips-about-the-home-office-deduction and other documents on that site.

Answer (score 1):

It will come down the percentage of time you use a specific area in your home.  For each business you will be asked to first designate a percentage of your home you use for that business, then the percentage of time you use it.  The space for both businesses might be the same, but the percentage of use would not.  You could not claim 100% for both businesses.  The combined petcentage of use could not exceed 100%.